# How can I color the clusters individually in R software?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I want to distinguish the clusters by color.

I am using the below mentioned code which distingushs the clusters with rectangles; however I would love if I can represent the clusters along with teminals with different colors.

`

```
cl <- as.hclust(tw)
plot(cl, col.axis = "#F38630", lwd = 3:1, main = '', ylab = '', 
     cex = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
title(ylab = "Height", mgp = c(2.2, 1, 0), cex.lab = 1.5)
par(lwd=3, mar=c(0,0,0,0), lty = 5)
rect.hclust(cl, 3, border = 5:7)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

So, if your data has cluster labels (not able to tell from your post because there is no data for `tw`), you can simply add `col=labels` as such:

```
plot(cl, col=labels, col.axis = "#F38630", lwd = 3:1, main = '', ylab = '', 
     cex = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5)
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Actually, I am using the twinspan() function (within TWINSPAN package), for which I have used species abundance data (species names in rows and sites in column. I have run: tw = twinspan(data)